# how to get download attribute behaviour in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

following html code does not properly work in safari. it saves file as 'unknown' without extension name. is there work around to save file by specifying a name in safari ?

```
<a href="data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333"
   download="somedata.csv">Example</a>
```

http://jsbin.com/duzuqedipo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Safari [simply doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) the download attribute (at least not as of April 2016), which is the only client side method of influencing file names.

Comment: is there way to overcome above issue on safari ?

Comment: That's the question that I just answered. 7 minutes later, the answer is still "No".

Comment: quentin - but  as a example, how gmail able to provide attachment downloading feature with correct file extension in safari such as image.png ?

Comment: @InfoAsith — They use HTTP URIs.